# DEFAULT NULL column when column created with NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, database

I created a table in `mysql`. Every column in my table I created with NOT NULL. What does the `NULL` value in my `DEFAULT` column mean? I never plan to have a NULL value in those columns.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| user_id    | binary(16)   | NO   | PRI |                   |       |
| first_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| last_name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| email      | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL              |       |
| digest     | binary(40)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| join_ts    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you don't have a default value for these columns.
If you have a default value, you can create an insert query without that column.
With your table, you must give a value to all the null default's columns